# create an 4-column Array from the 3D numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array of dimension(737,737,90) which contains the intensity values of type float32(i.e., Voxel Intensities). My query is How can i make an array that look a like A = [x-co_ordinate, y-co_ordinate, z-co_ordinate, I(x,y,z)].

where I(x,y,z) value is the array(737,737,90) as mentioned above is known.

I tried the "for" looping method, but failed to get an array like [x,y,z, I(x,y,z)] . If you have any solution to this in Python3.5, please do let me know.

The method tht I tried is

arr = array of shape(737,737,90) consists of values.

for x in arr.shape[0]:

```
for y in arr.shape[1]:

    for z in arr.shape[2]:

        A[] = [x,y,z, (arr[x,y,z])]
```

where arr[x,y,z] is the array of float values of dimension (737,737,90).

So i need the array like A[x,y,z,arr_value]. Is there any method to do this in python3.5

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Hi there! Many solutions are possible to solve your problem. Can you please clarify what you mean by the "for looping method"? Best post your code in a minimal and self-contained example. Then I'm sure someone can tell you what went wrong and how to do it right. :)

Comment: thank u for reply. I had edited the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to get all those indices with [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) and then stack it with the input array. The output would be in `(4, X, Y, Z)` format. So finally, to get it in `4` columns format, roll axes to push back the first axis.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
I = np.indices(arr.shape)
out = np.rollaxis(np.vstack((I,arr[None])),0,4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But One Thing I did not get it,  when I check the output, suppose if i check that accessing random index like out[200,200,30], it should give me single value which is corresponding to that x,y,z index But it shows the 4 values. Why?  If you let me know, it will be helpful.

Comment: @rajubhai Well you have listed in the question you want `A`, such that `A: [x,y,z,arr_value]`, which I assumed as a 4D array. So, when you index into its first three axes with `out[200,200,30]`, which is same as `out[200,200,30,:]`, you would get all the 4 elements, corresponding to the 4 columns. Why would you expect `out[200, 200, 30]` to be a single value? If you were expecting a single value, maybe you are looking to get that single value from input array itself with `arr[200,200,30]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was not bad. These are the issues:

- You forgot to loop over X
- To loop over a range of values you need to use `range`
- You need to initialize `A` before using it in the loop

.

```
A = []
for x in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for z in range(arr.shape[2]):
            A.append([x,y,z, arr[x,y,z]])
A = np.array(A)  # convert to array
```

Note that while this is a good start, it is a very inefficient solution because nested for loops are often slow in Python. A potentially faster but less readable solution could look like this:

```
n_voxels = np.prod(arr.shape)
A = np.vstack([np.unravel_index(np.arange(n_voxels), arr.shape), arr.ravel()]).T
```